# how to configure hardware trigger using python in pylon?

Tags: python, image-processing

Actually i wannna take an image from basler camera when an hardware trigger is passed an access the image for further processing.how to configure hardware trigger using python in pylon?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the trigger source and set it on.

```
from pypylon import pylon

camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice())
camera.Open()

camera.TriggerSource.SetValue("Line1")
camera.TriggerMode.SetValue("On")

camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)
grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)
```